# $(npm bin)/hugo --environment production /bin/bash: line 136: Unknown: command not found

Tags: npm, gitlab, hugo

I use [hugo](https://gohugo.io/) and [doks](https://github.com/h-enk/doks) and gitlab with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
---
image: node:latest

variables:
  HUGO_ENV: production
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install -g hugo

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - $(npm bin)/hugo --environment staging
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - test
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - $(npm bin)/hugo --environment production
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

This worked fine until last week where I git this error as of a sudden

```bash
$ $(npm bin)/hugo --environment production
/bin/bash: line 136: Unknown: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Interestingly, **nothing changed**, neither in the pipeline nor on hugo or the template I am using.

Comment: I would check the hugo version used, to see if it has changed. You can try to revert back to a previous version to debug.

Comment: Hugo is pinned in `packages.json` as `"hugo-bin": "^0.68.0",`

Comment: Why nom install hugo? Shouldn't it be npm install hugo-extended or hugo-bin?

Answer (score 2):

npm bin has been removed since npm version 9.0.0-pre.0 (see https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/CHANGELOG.md)

You simply can replace

```
$(npm bin)/xyz
```

by

```
$(npm_bin.sh)/xyz
```

where npm_bin.sh must be in $PATH and looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ./node_modules/.bin
```

Comment: Update: npx resp. npm exec does the job.

Answer (score 1):

1. Removed the following line

   ```
    - npm install -g hugo
   ```
2. Update `package.json` following the suggestions of [the theme](https://github.com/h-enk/doks/blob/master/package.json) I use:

   ```
   ...
   "devDependencies": {
     ....
     "hugo-installer": ">=4.0.1",
     ....
   },
   "otherDependencies": {
     "hugo": "0.107.0"
   }
   ```
3. Update path to hugo as follows

   ```
   ./node_modules/.bin/hugo/hugo --environment production
   ```